# Bias Variance decomposition loss function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, bias-variance-tradeoff

In the Bias Variance decomposition in linear regression of Bishop, it has :  However, in practice we have a data set D containing only a finite number N of data points, and consequently we do not know the regression function h(x) exactly. where h(x) = E[t|x]. What is the interpretation for h(x) and how is the exact knowledge of h(x) dependant on our data set ?

Answer (score 1):

When doing regression we're trying to answer the question, "given $x$ what should I expect $t$ to be, assuming these come from some joint distribution $P(x,t)$.  Of course the best answer would be the expected value of $t$ given $x$, defined as

$$
h(x) = \mathbb{E}_{P(t|x)} [t].
$$

This is what Bishop is calling the regression function.  Here's our problem, we don't know $P(t|x)$.  If we did we would be done (after some integration).  So instead we have to work with our finite sample which in will almost surely not perfectly represent the distribution.

If you think about estimating the heads rate of a coin.  If $p = 0.3$ it's very possible that we get 3 heads and 3 tails.  And there's practically no algorithm under the sun that will tell us to go with $0.3$.  So by dealing with a finite sample our estimate will vary from the true parameter.  How much it varies depends on the actual distribution, and the method we use to estimate.